# Timing with javascript performance.now()

Tags: javascript, timing, performance.now

I am trying to time the execution of my function in milliseconds. I use **performance.now()** in order to do that. I am able to get the time on the first run, but on the second, third, and so on runs I get 0 milliseconds.
Here is an example:

```
function someFunction (){
    var t0 = performance.now();
    //Function calculations
    var t1 = performance.now();
    Console.log(t1 - t0);
}
```

I launch the function onclick. It works when I first launch the page. It stops working on the second click. t0 and t1 get the same values and when I subtract them I get 0 for the time. Is there anyway around it? I don't necessarily need to use performance.now(). I just want to measure time in milliseconds.

Thank you.

**Update**
I think it has everything to do with the speed.
For example:

```html
    <html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function someFunction (){
        var t0 = performance.now();
        console.log(t0);
        //Function calculations
        //Some loop
        var counter = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { 
         counter ++;
     }
        var t1 = performance.now();
        console.log(t1);
        console.log(t1 - t0);
    }
    
    </script>
    
    <button type="button" onclick="someFunction()">Click me</button>
    </hmtl>
```

Works as I would expect, but with the loop `for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)` it doesn't.

Thank you for the pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe the browser optimizes the code in the first run, so following ones are so fast.

Comment: I'd suggest you show us the actual code you are trying to measure in a jsFiddle.  Other than that fact that it is `console.log(t1 - t0)` with a lowercase `c`, there is nothing wrong with the code you have shown so the timing is either literally so fast that it comes out as `0` ms or there is something else wrong in the code you are not showing.

Comment: Just copied your code and tested it. Every time it gives me results greater than 0. Maybe also provide what's the browser and operating system you're using?

Comment: Interesting. I have been testing it and most times I get a positive value. But sometimes I get a negative one! I thought that only happened with dates.

Comment: Windows 8.1 Chrome Browser

Comment: You could try Date.now() as an alternative, but I think @Oriol is right that the code has been optimized enough by the second run that its runtime is not measurable.  BTW, performance.now() is specified to measure microseconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: Take a read here, if you read nothing else  http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html

Comment: Thank you for your help guys. I just updated the original post. It has to be the optimization. I am implementing the Tiny Encryption Algorithm with Javascript. Browser must be optimizing it on the second run.

Answer (score 3):

The actual code you use will change the results here, and why the test comes to 0 as the result is a matter of speculation without that.

That said, micro benchmarks in JavaScript these days are subject to [optimizations](http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html). For example:

```
function spiffy() {
    /* long bit of code that
       loops and loops and runs in 
       O(n!) time then finally */ 
    return result; 
}
```

Spiffy!

Let's say `spiffy()` deterministically always outputs the same result. The optimizer is allowed to effectively run this as:

```
function spiffy() { 
    return 42; 
}
```

Which turns

```
function someFunction() {
    var t0 = performance.now();
    var result = spiffy();
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log(t1 - t0);
}
```

into a useless test result.

If you've got a bona-fide performance problem in your JavaScript app, I would profile it when it's running [slower than molasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_Molasses_Disaster) and analyze the busiest portions of your code. And I don't mean micro benchmarks, but [examining run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it), [look at the algorithm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059651624X) you're using in that section and see if there might be a better one for your circumstances, and finally, ask someone else about the *actual code* in question, *in the same context* it's running in.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am new to Javascript, and I did not know how the optimizer works. I think I figured out what the problem is. Again, thank you for the pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN doc:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

> The timestamp is not actually high-resolution. To mitigate security threats such as Spectre, browsers currently round the results to varying degrees. (Firefox started rounding to 1 millisecond in Firefox 60.) Some browsers may also slightly randomize the timestamp. The precision may improve again in future releases; browser developers are still investigating these timing attacks and how best to mitigate them.

In such case you should not rely on `performance.now()` in browsers, or only rely it in millisecond resolution (like `Date.now()` does).

One workaround, wrapping your code with another `for{}` loop with 1000 times, so the time spend on the wrapped code is roughly 1000 times of the original code.

```
function benchmark(func) {
  var start = Date.now()
  for (var i=0;i<1000;i++) {
    func();
  }
  var end = Date.now();
  var diff = (end - start) / 1000;
  console.log('running 1000 times, average time is '+ diff + 'ms');
}
benchmark(someFunction);
```

Or you can test your code in NodeJS, if your code has no DOM operation:

- [`process.hrtime()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time)
- [`performance.now`](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_performance_now)

Answer (score 0):

performance.now() upgraded and the question should be closed and not being **bumped** anymore

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now

> the timestamps returned by Performance.now() are not limited to
>   one-millisecond resolution. Instead, they represent times as
>   floating-point numbers with up to microsecond precision.

```html
  <html>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         function someFunction (){
            var t0 = performance.now();
            console.log(t0);
            //Function calculations
            //Some loop
            var counter = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) { 
             counter ++;
         }
            var t1 = performance.now();
            console.log(t1);
            console.log(t1 - t0);
        }
        
        </script>
        
        <button type="button" onclick="someFunction()">Click me</button>
        </hmtl>
```